# Interactive 3d Web Technology

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, webgl, dxf

I would like to use interactive 3D models in a web page. The required functionality is:

- Import dxf file which defines & displays a room.
- Add/move prebuilt objects from javascript
- Add/move lamp which cast shadows from javascript
- Return room dimensions to javascript
- Return object positions to javascript

Can I import dxf files into any WebGL engine?

I have a small repeat user base so a browser installation is no problem at all. Is there any plugin technology I could use? Java applets? Unity? Can I use an OpenGL engine as a plugin? How about a java3d applet?

I will start with desktop but would need to be targeting tablets soon and mobiles in two years or so.

I am becoming convinced I will need to hire an expert to write this but I want to understand the options.  Can you recommend a suitable technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think WebGL is an excellent choice for this application; the graphics functions you describe are well within its capabilities. I can't comment on model loading, though, as I'm not familiar with WebGL engines.

However, mobile is a big wrinkle. Regarding the techniques you mention:

- WebGL is supported in Chrome and Firefox for Android. On iOS, Mobile Safari does not *enable* WebGL, but an implementation exists (used strictly for in-app ads), so it is likely that there may be broader WebGL support in the future (possibly requiring a custom web view wrapper to enable it).
- Java applets are not supported by any browser on either Android or iOS.
- Unity is a viable choice; the Unity Web Player browser plugin allows embedding Unity content in a web page. However, there is no such plugin for mobile-OS devices; Unity content may be *compiled into a application* for iOS or Android but it cannot be viewed within a web page.

  **News as of August 2014:** Unity has announced that the upcoming Unity 5 will include publishing to JavaScript + WebGL (no plugin required). Assuming this works as promised, you can use Unity if your target platform has a browser with WebGL support.

So, if you absolutely need cross-platform 3D including iOS **right now**, Unity is where it's at, but WebGL is a good choice for desktop and Android now and likely to improve on mobile in the future, and is the only way to embed 3D *in a web page, not an app* across desktop and Android.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't need mobile immediately and webgl does look the way to go. However, I cannot see how to import a dxf file - is this possible with any current webgl engine? I cannot be the only person to want this but I cannot see a solution. I presume it is possible...maybe I will have to get it done!

Comment: I just searched “[webgl dxf](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=webgl+dxf&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)” and immediately found that [CopperLicht](http://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/features.html) claims to support DXF import. That said, it is quite likely that you will benefit from preprocessing the models into some other format “native” to your choice of 3D engine and having parameters relevant to it, so I wouldn't worry about the client-side engine supporting a particular model format too much — try things!

Answer (score 1):

WebGL is not the only way to embed 3D in a web page - see phoria.js:
http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/

https://github.com/kevinroast/phoria.js

Also three.js has a canvas rendering for without web-gl.

Phoria.js and others like it will work on iPhone/iPad and Android phones that don't support web-gl. Of course, the performance is MUCH lower but if you don't have complex models and want it to work everywhere...