# Simple ways to create content-rich 3D WebPage/WebApp

Tags: web, 3d, webgl

I want to create a an interactive 3D based web page/application wherein, I can draw simple 3D shapes, shadows, custom 3D models (say .ply, .obj). I want this page to contain rich 3D content and should support both MAC and Windows. I am new to web development and very naive in coding. I have basic exposure on creating a webpage/web-application.

I understand all this can be done using WebGL ([Interactive 3d Web Technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387981/interactive-3d-web-technology))
. But it seems that building web pages using webGL native or using libraries such as Three.js is quite cumbersome. Is there a simpler tool/library/way to simply drop and style 3D elements?

Comment: Have a look at the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/webgl/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lack of such high level libraries/frameworks which live atop either WebGL or HTML5 canvas ... here is just the tip of the iceberg ... with some nice creations thrown in ... enjoy

https://playcanvas.com/

http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/

http://d3js.org/

http://codepen.io

https://www.blend4web.com/en/

http://acko.net/

http://phant.io/

http://www.geoweb3d.com/

https://plot.ly

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

http://dadaviz.com/

[stuff-that-every-programmer-should-know](http://c0de517e.blogspot.com/2014/06/stuff-that-every-programmer-should-know.html)

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/

http://bl.ocks.org/jinroh/7524988

https://haxiomic.github.io/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/html5/